# How to edit manu bar of blogger tample?

Tags: blogger

I have imported a blogger template in my blog http://technojini.blogspot.in/ and I want to edit template according to my requirements. 
1. I want to edit menu bar or template (want to change categories and subcategories)
2. I want to create new page on each category of menu bar 
3. I want to fix Image size of slider. 
Right now I have changed slider images but the default Image size is taking by slider which is not looking good. I want to set image size according to slider size.

Please give some solutions and help me to setup blog.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I solved problem my self.

Edit template - Edit HTML - search given code - Change names with required name in

tag.

```
<html>
<ul class='menus menu-secondary'>
  <li><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>SEO</a>
<ul class='children'>
 <li><a href='http://technojini.blogspot.in/p/on-page-seo.html'>On Page</a></li>
 <li><a href='#'>Off Page</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
 <li><a href='#'>Digital Marketing  </a>
 <ul class='children'>
 <li><a href='#'>Google+</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Facebook</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>`<li><a href='#'>Infographics</a> </li> 
<li><a href='#'>Quotes</a>
<ul class='children'>
<li><a href='#'>Love Quotes</a>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Motivational Quotes</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Business Quotes</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Health</a>
</li>
<li><a href='http://technojini.blogspot.in/p/about-us.html'>About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
</html>
```

and replace '#' with category URL manually.